# what is wrong with the following C function?

Tags: c

i was asked to find two main issues in the following code.

```
char* name(char* first_name, char* last_name){
char buff[100];
sprintf (buff, "%s %s", first_name, last_name);
return (buff);
}
```

i found only one issue. the buff array was declared inside the function scope. meaning when returning to the function who called this function, it will return a pointer to something "empty" (that is not buff array).
i couldn't find the second issue.
can you please assist?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible buffer overflow. Parameters should be `const char*`.

Comment: const char is only part of the problem. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One is what you said, returning a local variable.
One is if the person has a long name, a fixed buff[100] will overflow.

Comment: as aschelper pointed it out in a comment, the arguments also should be const-qualified for safety.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer overflow, using `sprintf` instead of `snprintf` (somewhat redundant, I know), parameters should be `const char*`, no null checks, unnecessary parentheses around buff, no indentation, did I get it yet?

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't know how big `first_name` and `last_name` are so that leaves you open to crashes and buffer overrun hacks.
2. Check first_name and last_name for NULL before using.

Comment: I disagree with point #2. An `assert`ion might be acceptable, but there is no reason to check for `NULL` here; Consider code designed with consistency for `sprintf` in mind, which expects the caller to check for `NULL`. In order to be consistent with the design of the C standard, `name` should also expect the caller to check for `NULL`.

Comment: Good point.  Interesting side note - doing a sprintf with %s and NULL, the MSFT compiler actually puts the characters `(null)` in the buffer.

Comment: Passing `NULL` corresponding to a `%s` directive is undefined behaviour. It's not wise to rely upon that behaviour; Microsoft might take it away from you in future upgrades, and other vendors certainly aren't required to support it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things more than that wrong, in my opinion.  First, first_name and last_name should be `const char *` since they're not modified... the interface should specify that.  Second, there is no error or bounds checking on the lengths of the strings... you could easily have buffer overrun on the stack... major security issue.